# How can I atomically reorder array items in MongoDB?

Tags: php, mongodb

I have a `playlists` collection. Each document in the collection contains an `entries` field, that is an array.

How can I change the order of `entries` in a playlist, atomically?
(e.g. If another user tries *at the same time* to `$push` a new entry, I want to make sure that the new entry is `$push`ed only after the reordering has happened)

If I do a `find()`, then reorder in PHP, then `update()`, I might lose the new `$push`ed entry if the operation is not atomic.

This is a sample playlist object:

```
{
    "_id" : "playlist1",
    "title" : "Playlist One",
    "entries" : [
            {
                    "class" : "song",
                    "identifier" : "song1"
            },
            {
                    "class" : "song",
                    "identifier" : "song2"
            },
            {
                    "class" : "song",
                    "identifier" : "song3"
            }
    ]
}
```

---

**Edit:**

I think I found a possible solution, using `execute()`:

> Running JavaScript in the database takes a write lock, meaning it blocks other operations.

(from http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.execute.php)

I just need to execute the code (`find()` + `reorder()` + `update()`) on the MongoDB Server.

Still, if you have another idea that doesn't involve "code within a string" (e.g. `$func = "function() { do_something(); return \"something else\" }"`), please share it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using eval() to block operations is a side effect of the current implementation, not a feature to rely on.

The MongoDB wiki has a page with information on [Atomic Operations](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Atomic+Operations).

A relevant strategy for your use case would be ["update if current"](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Atomic+Operations#AtomicOperations-%22UpdateifCurrent%22):

1. Fetch the object.
2. Modify the object locally.
3. Send an update request that says "update the object to this new value if it still matches its old value".